# Reportviewer: Subscript in a label

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010

I am using MS reportviewer, C# (VS 2010)

In a tablix column header, is it possible to display a letter as subscript in a label?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "not really". FWIW, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/vsreportcontrols/thread/73836f9d-7a51-4bb4-954b-4b10edd60d6f